# Why "vendor-chunk" should only be used for Development?

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I read the following in [Angular docs](https://angular.io/cli/build):

> --vendor-chunk
>
> Generate a separate bundle containing only vendor libraries. This option should only used for development.

But there are no details about why this option should only be used for development. I've read in other places that they recommend to separate the vendor chunk so clients don't need to download it again when we release a new version of the application (because the main chunk changes, but the vendor chunk doesn't necessarily change).

Why is Angular's docs recommend to use this only in development?

Comment: Have you found out anything regarding this?

Comment: Nope, I didn't get any answer

Comment: Any news related to this?

Comment: Nope, I never got an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I was searching for it

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is because tree shaking and other build optimizations will generally result in a smaller overall package size if you do not force the vendor files to be split into a separate chuck.

Overall, the recommendation from the Angular team is probably correct in the large majority of cases.

From the [current docs on build optimizations](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/docs/design/build-system.md#optimizations):

> **Optimizations**
>
> The build system contains optimizations aimed at **improving the performance (for development builds) or the size of artifacts (for production builds)**. These are often mutually exclusive and thus we cannot just default to always using them.
>
> **Development optimizations**
>
> Development optimizations focus on reducing rebuild time ...
>
> Computation needed to bundle code grows with its total size because of the cost of string concatenation and source map operations. Third party dependencies that are initially loaded are **split into a synchronously loaded chunk called vendor**. Splitting the infrequently changed vendor code from the frequently changed source code thus **helps make rebuilds faster**.
>
> **Production optimizations**
>
> Angular CLI focuses on enabling tree-shaking (removing unused modules) and dead code elimination (removing unused module code). These two categories have **high potential for size reduction** because of network effects: removing code can lead to more code being removed.
> ...
> One significant pitfall of this optimization strategy is the use of code splitting. Using code splitting is desirable in order to speed up loading of web apps by deferring code that is not necessary on the initial load. But since code splitting necessarily makes use of module loading, it is at odds with Terser-based optimizations.

If you go down the road of trying to figure out if you should enable the vendor chunk in your app, make sure when comparing size to look at both the size on disk but also the transferred size assuming you are using some form of server compression like gzip or similar. It is possible for there to be an insignificant size difference on disk, but for the compressed size differences to be significant due to how the compression works.
In practice, you may find it it not a large difference in size for your app.

If the size is a wash, then the decision becomes whether or not you frequently update vendors/third party modules or not. If you do, there is again not a huge benefit in splitting out a separate vendor chunk file. Whether in 2 files or 1, the same amount of code needs to be downloaded before the app can start (might have very minor savings from downloading in parallel - test it for your app, but again, likely insignificant).

If you do NOT change your vendor code very often, and you verify the file size differences are negligible and the file hash stays the same on rebuilds generally (optimizations can cause the file contents and hash to change even if your vendors have not), then there might be a small benefit for your users because when you do publish a new app version, only the core app code needs to be downloaded, while the vendor chunk can continue to be used if it hasn't changed from the previously cached version.

A tiny bit more from an [older version of the Angular docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/e2273ffd85d591f04b883c1c114f90b9d422732a/docs/documentation/build.md#--build-optimizer-and---vendor-chunk) (mostly accurate but note that the optimization methods are different since this was written)

> --build-optimizer and --vendor-chunk
> When using Build Optimizer the vendor chunk will be disabled by default. You can override this with --vendor-chunk=true.
>
> **Total bundle sizes with Build Optimizer are smaller if there is no separate vendor chunk because having vendor code in the same chunk as app code makes it possible ... to remove more unused code.**